# LINQ group customer list by enum based on count

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

My need is to group a list of customers (List) where Customer contains this enum:

```
public enum CustomerType
{
  type1,
  type2,
  type3,
  type4,
  type5
}
```

by type and number of items per type (in this case 50), for example if customers contain:

```
70  type1,
120  type2 and
51  type5
```

your answer should return a list of Dictionary objects like:

```
Object 1:
50  type1,
50  type2 and
50  type5

Object 2:
20  type1,
50  type2 and
1  type5

Object 3:
50  type2
```

Basically the Dictionary object works like a page that contains 50 items of any type.

Comment: I can't see the relation between example data and example results. Can You provide some details ?

Comment: @mas_oz2k1 You mean the `Customer` class is something like this? `class Customer { public CustomerType  Type { get; set; } public int Id { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; } }`

Comment: He wants to implement paging, sort of.  With a page size of 50.

Comment: We should assume that object 1 actually returns a `List<Customer>`?

Comment: No, I tend to add a sample answer with the typical Customer class as everybody is familiar with it to avoid going backward and forwards.  apologies if it sounds like a test. Robert got it right my aim is to page the data as I need to generate text files that can contain up to page size per every type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?  It returns an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Customer>>`, not a `List<Dictionary<?,Customer>>` partly because I'm not sure what you would want as a key.

```
var pageSize=3; // Change to 50
var cust=new[] {
  new {CustomerType=1,CustomerName="A"},
  new {CustomerType=1,CustomerName="B"},
  new {CustomerType=1,CustomerName="C"},
  new {CustomerType=1,CustomerName="D"},
  new {CustomerType=1,CustomerName="E"},
  new {CustomerType=1,CustomerName="F"},
  new {CustomerType=1,CustomerName="G"},
  new {CustomerType=1,CustomerName="H"},
  new {CustomerType=2,CustomerName="I"},
  new {CustomerType=2,CustomerName="J"},
  new {CustomerType=2,CustomerName="K"},
  new {CustomerType=2,CustomerName="L"},
  new {CustomerType=2,CustomerName="M"},
  new {CustomerType=2,CustomerName="N"},
  new {CustomerType=3,CustomerName="O"},
  new {CustomerType=3,CustomerName="P"},
  new {CustomerType=4,CustomerName="Q"}
};
var max=cust.GroupBy(c=>c.CustomerType).Select(c=>c.Count()).Max();
var dict=Enumerable
  .Range(0,(max-1)/pageSize+1)
  .Select(page=>
    cust.GroupBy(c=>c.CustomerType)
      .Select(c=>
        c.Skip(page*pageSize)
          .Take(pageSize))
    .SelectMany(c=>c));
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: If it is a big query, there is probably more efficient ways of doing it than the way I did, but it was quick enough to write it this way.  I'd likely group them by type then implement a custom iterator that used 5 internal iterators to pull them out as you enumerated if you need faster, but that's not pure built-in LINQ.

Comment: Yes, kind of what I am looking for my answer List<Dictionary<CustomeType,Customer>>  , thanks a lot - your comment raise an interesting  question, if I can manage to get the data as a dictionary of (customer types, customer) - that will avoid some group by calls and iterator. Is this correct?